# How to use Esri data in QGIS using ArcGIS REST API Connector (beta)

Tags: qgis, arcgis-rest-api

I'd like to include Esri's aerial images in QGIS maps.  I am using QGIS 2.18.3

I have discovered the ArcGIS REST API Connector (beta) http://giswiki.hsr.ch/ArcGIS_REST_API_Connector_QGIS_Plugin

However, I can't work out what URL to place in the box that the plugin launches.  The closest I can get is from this page http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/3 there is a link in the top right page for 'API reference' http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/sdk/rest/index.html#//02ss0000005t000000

but this page doesn't make it clear what URL to point to.

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question.  Beta software questions are generally more appropriately asked in a support environment with the developers (GIS SE is not intended to replace native Tech Support).

Comment: The secondary question has been removed. I think the Q is appropriate here as I think the answer lies more in understanding how to use the API than the plugin (which is a free community written plugin, not provided by Esri).

Comment: If the plugin doesn't include documentation sufficient to find a working REST endpoint, then I'd put the fault at the plugin. It should certainly be able to get what is needed from that URL.

Comment: QGIS versions >=2.16 has the built in Add ArcGIS MapServer Layer button on the Layer toolbar, have you tried using this feature?